# Dry Cabinet not maintaining 45 rh

Tags: humidity, dry-box, dry-cabinet

I have a 150L dry cabinet with a electric hygrometer. I have set the humidity to 45% rh but the digital meter is showing 36% rh. The dry cabinet is in air conditioned room( which operates occasionally). I cannot understand why rh value is falling below 45%, previously during the winter season it was working perfectly. The rh values stayed in the range of 44-45%. I am at my wits end as to why it is malfunctioning now. Is it a technical fault or an ambient temperature related issue?

Comment: Hi Amlan! I think to help you reasonably well with your problem, a bit more of information would be quite useful. For starters, it's not even a question, merely a statement; phrasing it as actual question helps finding out what exactly you want. Further, the more you can tell us about what you have tried to analyze the problem can help guiding us in the right direction. As it stands, this does not read to me like a particularly photography-centric question, maybe some more information can help us nail down the issue faster, or provide a better place to ask.

Comment: @Cornelius I have updated my question to give more detailed description about my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd guess that your dry cabinet probably only dehumidifies.  It is kind of like if you have your AC turned on and set to 70 Fahrenheit.  If it is 32 degrees outside, you're AC doesn't do anything because it isn't needed, but your temperature is going to drop much lower than 70.

Similarly, your room has a lower relative humidity than you are trying to maintain, so there is nothing for the dry cabinet to do.  It is displaying that the relative humidity is already lower.  You would need a humidifier to bring the humidity up in the box if you needed to actually regulate it exactly.

Alternately, it could be that the meter is actually broken, you could try putting in a wet sponge as BobT suggested below and see if the value goes up or not.  If it does, then the room humidity is "probably" just lower than you have it set and it is working ok, if the value doesn't go up, then most likely the meter itself is broken and may need to be serviced or replaced.

Comment: I think AJH has a point. Does the cabinet humidify as well as dehumidify? If you put a wet sponge (for example) into the cabinet does the humidity stabilize at 45%?

Comment: @BobT I am gonna try the wet sponge experiment to see if the humidity is changing or not.